# Extra checkbox in tableselect rows

Tags: forms

I have a list form in a module, which is giving me three columns, the first of which is a checkbox column.

```
function popups_list_form($form, &$form_state){
        global $base_url;
        $header = array("Title", "Popup");

        $result = db_query("SELECT * FROM popups"); 
        }
        # build the table fields
        $rows = array();
        $options = array();
        $ppups = array();

        foreach ($result as $row){                  
            $rows[$row->popup_id] = array($row->title, $row->popup_org_name);
         }

        $form['table'] = array(
            '#type' => 'tableselect',
            '#header' => $header,
            '#options' => $rows,
            '#default_value' => $ppups,
            '#empty' => t('No Popups Available'),
        );            
        return $form;   
    }
```

Why is it happening?

Comment: Don't you see missing `"` here?

Comment: Now i added ". But this " is not causing that checkbox to show in view.

Comment: Hi, sreekanth. A guess: I usually use keys when building $header and $options; e.g. `$header = array('title' => 'Title', ...)`, then `$options = array($id => array('title' => $row->title, ...)`. Yours are missing. Might this be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you are using a [#tableselect](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#tableselect) form element, which is clearly described as follows:

> A table created with a far left column of radios or checkboxes. Build the table headings and columns with the #headers property, and the rows with the #options property. See Adding checkboxes to a table for a full explanation.

What you are looking for is a table, which is a theme function. See for example the following code, used by Drupal core.

```
function aggregator_view() {
  $result = db_query('SELECT f.fid, f.title, f.url, f.refresh, f.checked, f.link, f.description, f.hash, f.etag, f.modified, f.image, f.block, COUNT(i.iid) AS items FROM {aggregator_feed} f LEFT JOIN {aggregator_item} i ON f.fid = i.fid GROUP BY f.fid, f.title, f.url, f.refresh, f.checked, f.link, f.description, f.hash, f.etag, f.modified, f.image, f.block ORDER BY f.title');

  $output = '<h3>' . t('Feed overview') . '</h3>';

  $header = array(
    t('Title'),
    t('Items'),
    t('Last update'),
    t('Next update'),
    array(
      'data' => t('Operations'),
      'colspan' => '3',
    ),
  );
  $rows = array();
  foreach ($result as $feed) {
    $rows[] = array(
      l($feed->title, "aggregator/sources/$feed->fid"),
      format_plural($feed->items, '1 item', '@count items'),
      ($feed->checked ? t('@time ago', array('@time' => format_interval(REQUEST_TIME - $feed->checked))) : t('never')),
      ($feed->checked && $feed->refresh ? t('%time left', array('%time' => format_interval($feed->checked + $feed->refresh - REQUEST_TIME))) : t('never')),
      l(t('edit'), "admin/config/services/aggregator/edit/feed/$feed->fid"),
      l(t('remove items'), "admin/config/services/aggregator/remove/$feed->fid"),
      l(t('update items'), "admin/config/services/aggregator/update/$feed->fid", array('query' => array('token' => drupal_get_token("aggregator/update/$feed->fid")))),
    );
  }
  $output .= theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows, 'empty' => t('No feeds available. <a href="@link">Add feed</a>.', array('@link' => url('admin/config/services/aggregator/add/feed')))));

  $result = db_query('SELECT c.cid, c.title, COUNT(ci.iid) as items FROM {aggregator_category} c LEFT JOIN {aggregator_category_item} ci ON c.cid = ci.cid GROUP BY c.cid, c.title ORDER BY title');

  $output .= '<h3>' . t('Category overview') . '</h3>';

  $header = array(t('Title'), t('Items'), t('Operations'));
  $rows = array();
  foreach ($result as $category) {
    $rows[] = array(l($category->title, "aggregator/categories/$category->cid"), format_plural($category->items, '1 item', '@count items'), l(t('edit'), "admin/config/services/aggregator/edit/category/$category->cid"));
  }
  $output .= theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows, 'empty' => t('No categories available. <a href="@link">Add category</a>.', array('@link' => url('admin/config/services/aggregator/add/category')))));

  return $output;
}
```

In your case, your code should simply be similar to the following one. (See also the comments in the code.)

```
function popups_list_form($form, &$form_state) {
  // This variable is never used; remove it.
  // global $base_url;

  $header = array("Title", "Popup");
  $result = db_query("SELECT * FROM popups");

  // The following bracket is wrong placed. Remove it from your code.
  // }

  $rows = array();

  foreach ($result as $row) {                   
    $rows[] = array($row->title, $row->popup_org_name);
  }

  $form['table'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#empty' => t('No Popups Available'),
  );

  return $form;   
}
```